# Is there a way to change the individual Visibility properties of each item in a listView?

Tags: xaml, listview

I've got a .xaml inspection form that pulls up a list of questions, each with a good & bad response, and a radio button to fill in whether the inspected item was fine or not- if there is an issue for any question, I want an editor to appear beneath the question for the user to explain what the problem is. However, I don't know a way to individually bind each question's note's visibility, or if it's even doable. Moreover, my radio button to make the notes appear doesn't recognize the Clicked or OnClicked property.

This is the code to show the questions thus far- it takes in a list of questionIDs, and their associated questions, good responses, bad responses, and has room for notes if something is reported as wrong.  So far I've had CheckedChanged properties that call methods that change the visibility of the notes, though that changes the visibility of every notes section in the list.

```
<StackLayout x:Name="Layout" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ListView x:Name="lvQuestions" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid Padding="5,5,5,5">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label x:Name="lblQuestion" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Question}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                    <RadioButton x:Name="goodButton" Content="{Binding GoodResponseType}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  CheckedChanged="goodMethodThatHidesNotes"/>
                                    <RadioButton x:Name="badButton" Content="{Binding BadResponseType}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" CheckedChanged="badMethodThatShowsNotes"/>
                                    <Editor x:Name="Notes" Placeholder="Explain Problem here..." Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsVisible="false" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" MaxLength="50"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
```